# URL rewrite with .htaccess for wildcard domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the url with wildcard from:

> https://any.example.com

To:

> https://example.com/fixed/any

'any' is any string and 'fixed' is fixed string.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show `VirtualHost` config of your wildcard domains?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting some rewrite rules like this in your `.htaccess` file:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Make sure it's not an actual file or 
# directory, being accessed. If you wish.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Match the subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$

# Rewrite the request to the main domain:
# %1: The subdomain matched against HTTP_HOST in the previous RewriteCond.
# $1: The request URI.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/fixed/%1/$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Feel free to drop the `L` flag, if it's not the last rewrite rule. See [RewriteRule Flags](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) for more information on this.

You can [test it online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).

[image]